# pycharm run command keyboard shortcut differences?

Tags: pycharm

Is it Shift+F10 or Ctrl+Shift+F10

Both works, but why not have just one. Is there any functional difference between the two techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is just `Run`, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is `Run Context Configuration`

You can check them by `Settings -> Keymap -> Find Actions by Shortcut` (a small button next to the search field).

`Run` will execute a script run last time or any active configuration, while `Run Context Configuration` may run the script in active tab, though it maybe hasn't any configuration or been run before.